# React Native: Import image conditionally for different 'applicationId' flavors

Tags: react-native

I have 2 flavors in Android (or Schemes in iOS), the 'main' and the 'aba' one:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 39
    versionName "1.29.39"
}

productFlavors {
    main {

    }
    aba {
        applicationIdSuffix ".aba"
        manifestPlaceholders = [appName: "ABA PRODUCT"]
    }
}
```

Inside `React Native` I want to require a different `img`, conditional on the flavor so that the production build does not include 2 images but just the proper one.

**What "compile-time" variable is exposed for this case?**

For example, if this variable is called `__APPLICATIONID_` then we would do this in order to get the "dead-code elimination" benefit and not require 2 images but just 1:

```
 var productLogo;

 if (__APPLICATIONID_ === 'com.myapp') {productLogo = require('../img/logo.png')};

 if (__APPLICATIONID_ === 'com.myapp.aba') {productLogo = require('../img/logoAba.png')};
```

Then in JSX:

```
       <Image
            source={productLogo}
       />
```

Thanks!